# Online fantasy story about puzzles and a girl who remembers the future but not the past

Tags: story-identification, online-resources

When I was a kid, maybe 15-19 years ago but possibly more, my Dad printed off chapters of an online story for me. I can't remember much about it, or what it was called. I think the puzzles were beyond me at the time, but I'd like to find it and attempt them again.

Things I remember:

- It was a fantasy story that included magic heavily.
- It was being released online, one chapter a week (or perhaps my Dad simply presented it to me that way).
- The main character, a girl, had a reversed memory. She remembered her future, but not her past.
- There were puzzles for the reader to solve in the story. I can't remember what form they took, but I believe there was one larger puzzle across the whole story the smaller puzzles were required to solve.
- Each chapter included a single, circular illustration with lots of detail. This picture had elements you needed to spot, perhaps to solve the puzzles. The imagery was quite dark.
- The girl had a number of companions. Perhaps they accumulated over the course of the story?
- I remember one image had glass jars of things suspended in formaldehyde (it sticks out because it was the first time I ever heard the word).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This must be [*Planetarium*](http://www.beholder.co.uk/planetarium/).

Screenshot of the first puzzle:

[image: puzzle 1]

Note that you can even see the jars of things apparently suspended in formaldehyde.

Quoting from [this review](http://www.eblong.com/zarf/gamerev/planetarium.html) (emphasis mine):

> Planetarium is a bit of surreality... I want to call it a fairy tale, but really it isn't. **A girl (who can remember the future instead of the past)** and a mathemagician (who achieves the same effect by the precision of his computations) set off on a journey. They are drawn by a mysterious love-letter that the girl received. We poor readers don't know who sent it. The girl and the mathemagician, however, with their different insights into fate... well, the story goes on.
>
> [...]
>
> Format? The story is divided into twelve chapters. **Each part has a single illustration (hand-drawn by the author, Dave Whiteland) and several chunks of text, describing various things in the illustration.** Click around to find out what's what. It's a typical hypertext exploratory mode, although less interactive than most computer games.
>
> Planetarium is actually closer to the classic puzzle-books (Masquerade, Maze, the bee book) than to a computer game. **It's a story with puzzles embedded in it**; but you don't have to solve the puzzles to see the whole story. Puzzles are not barriers to advancement.
>
> Instead, Planetarium paces itself by -- ahem -- clockwork. **The first chapter is always available. However, to become involved, you must sign onto the web site** (free registration). One week after you first sign on, part 2 becomes available to you. **Every week thereafter, another part is made accessible**, until you have all twelve. In the thirteenth week, you get to see the puzzle solutions, and the game tells you how well you did. That's it.